# How to detect when DOM is ready after *ngIf condition is set to true

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I have an Angular 2 (Ionic 2) application where I hide some elements using an `*ngIf` if the network is offline, and show another button, "retry".

When I click the retry button, if the network is back I then want to reshow the elements hidden by the `*ngIf`. Also I then need to reference some of them via `@ViewChild` (e.g. an Ionic 2 slider to get it's current index). My problem is that these elements are not all defined when I try to get a reference to them in the same function call that sets my property bound to the `*ngIf` back to true.

I have tried calling from within a setTimeout but this does not seem to be very safe - some DOM elements are back but not all.

Is there a way to know then the DOM is ready with all the elements that were hidden by the `*ngIf`, or do I need to find some other way of doing this (not using the `*ngIf`, so elements are not actually removed).

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do what you want by looking at the onStable event emitted via the NgZone:

In the component template:

```
<button (click)="showFoo = !showFoo">toggle</button>
<div *ngIf="showFoo" #foo >foo</div>
```

In your component class

```
@ViewChild('foo') foo: ElementRef;
showFoo = false;

constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
   zone.onStable.subscribe(() => {
     console.log(this.foo);
     // this will log either undefined or an ElementRef as you toggle
   });
}
```

Here's a plunk showing it working: https://plnkr.co/edit/jKSaEI0XUcJQehZnJTxB

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion and certainly seems to work in the example. I added it into my project, and it did fire, but one of my ion-selects were still not available when I tried to access it within this event. I have since gone to just toggling the visibility in this case since this does not remove anything from the dom.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to understand [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html),

[image]

I think the `ngAfterViewInit()` would help you with this,

> ngAfterViewInit()  Respond after Angular initializes the component's
>   views and child views.
>
> Called once after the first ngAfterContentChecked().
>
> A component-only hook.